# Минимальное значение для float

Tags: c++

Какое значение нужно присваивать переменной типа `float`, чтобы с помощью неё найти максимум: `std::numeric_limits<float>::min()` или `std::numeric_limits<float>::lowest()`, или др.?

Comment: Найти максимум чего?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну, поскольку о `min` пишут

> min returns the minimum positive normalized value

т.е. это малое *положительное* число, то, если вы работаете во всем диапазоне - включая отрицательные числа - лучше использовать `lowest`. Если только положительные - то `0` :)

Answer (score 3):

Есть одно значение, которое будет меньше, чем возвращенное `lowest`. Это:

> `-std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity()`

Следующий код [выведет](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Fcc8O7Mb5ytjKHlu) `true`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha 
        << (-std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity() < std::numeric_limits<float>::lowest()) 
        << "\n";
}
```

Перед использованием имеет смысл проверить, что `std::numeric_limits<float>::has_infinity == true`.